# Accessing control events of email form

Tags: vsto, office-interop, office-2010

I am trying to develop an add-on for outlook which requires handling control changes.

For instance I need to do some stuff when email subject is changed. To do this, I need to access text change event of subject texbox.

I was just wondering whether anyone has done such thing or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the [PropertyChange event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171326%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

> Occurs when a standard property (for example, Subject or To) of a
>   Microsoft Outlook item is changed. The property name is passed to the
>   event so that you can determine which property was changed.

Comment: I tried.. but it does not fie when I type in body field. however, if I preset body field when the form is loaded, it fires...

Comment: it looks like it fires when you tab to another field... there should be a way to access text_changed event of this body textbox...

Comment: The events are kind of sparse, unfortunately - did you want to fire on every keypress?

Comment: Yes, I did... does it look impossible?

Comment: It's not impossible, but the alternatives get complex! You could use WinAPI calls to hook the event; you'd probably start with [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Or, the horrible solution would be to use a timer to check the field contents periodically.